# Use curl with apache HttpPost object

Tags: java, curl, http-post

I would like to dump the complete content of an `org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost` object so I can use curl to debug what's wrong with this object. Is there anyway to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this java class, .net class or something else? How is this question related to apache at all?

Comment: This is java. I'm sorry for the wrong tag. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't quite clear what are you trying to do, but I guess that you want to see what is sent from Java to some remote endpoint. You can intercept actual HTTP request and there are  tools for that:

- [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)
- [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org)
- [TunnelliJ](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=155) plugin for IntelliJ IDEA

Having intercepted request you'll see its raw form, something like

```
POST /endpoint HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Accept: text/xml
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 342
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.2.1 (java 1.5)

<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
/// etc
```

Having a dump, you'll be able to reproduce request with curl and modify some parts of it to see if they are wrong.

Fiddler2 is simple to start with. TunnelliJ is even simpler, but tied to IDEA. Wireshark is lower-level and allows to intercept any traffic, not only HTTP. But it demands some skills to use it.